# Error code in Datapower

Tags: xslt, ibm-datapower

I'm using MPGW service which will hit the CICS service and return back the response.
This is my flow.  UI --> DP MPGW gateway --> MPGW Service --> CICS service.

In case of "No data Found" response from CICS, I just want to set the error code as 100 and message as "No data found" and pass on to UI. But everytime datapower is return 500 Internal server error to UI.

I'm using errorHandler.xslt to check the fault code from CICS and setting the error code and error message.

Is there something I need to change the dp:response-header('x-dp-response-code')? If so how to do this?

Note: Process Backend error : 'On' in both the MPGW(gateway and service).

Comment: Is there some XSLT code involved? If so, could you please show it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

If a response contains 500 not found error. Do a dp:reject at the response rule.This will take control to error rule. At error rule, configure an xslt and set below values:

`<dp:set-variable name="'var://service/error-protocol-response'" value="'100'" />
<dp:set-variable name="'var://service/error-protocol-reason-phrase'" value="'No Data Found'" />`

Answer (score 0):

As per https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014432297 you want:

Within an Error Rule:

Within a Response Rule:

That should do the trick for an MPGW I believe.